# Error : package android.support.annotation does not exist in ionic 5 by using sms-retriever

Tags: android, capacitor, ionic5, sms-retriever-api

I am using [sms-retriver](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sms-retriever) for getting app hash string and I'm getting an error

> package android.support.annotation does not exist

And I resolved this error by changing

> import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

above code to the below code

> import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

The change is happening in the file path

> android\capacitor-cordova-android-plugins\src\main\java\com\codingsans\ionic\smsRetriever\AndroidSmsRetriever.java

This file is not able to push into repository and getting the same error in the ionic hub.

Answer (score 11):

That happens when a cordova plugin uses the old android support libraries instead of the new AndroidX support libraries. Capacitor uses AndroidX and you can't use non AndroidX libraries.
You can use jettifier to patch the plugins

```
npm install jetifier
npx jetify
npx cap sync android
```

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v3/android/troubleshooting#error-package-androidsupport-does-not-exist

Answer (score 3):

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
```

this may help you.